# Godot: После метода show кнопка не понимает, что на ней мышка

Tags: godot

mouse_entered меня более чем устраивают в работе, но если навести мышку на то место, где вскоре появится кнопка через show, то метод не сработает. Как можно проверить, что мышка находится на texture_button и запустить метод выделения кнопки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, Вы пытаетесь реализовать свою функцию прямо в сигнале от `Area2D` (в `_on_area_2d_mouse_entered`), данная функция подает сигнал только когда в её зоне появляется курсор мыши и новый сигнал в функции `_on_area_2d_mouse_exited` - когда курсор мыши уходит из зоны.

```
var flag = false # bool значение "переключателя"

func _process(delta):
    if flag == true: # Когда мышь в зоне
        {Ваш код}
    elif flag == false: # Когда мышь не в зоне
        {Ваш код}
    
func _on_area_2d_mouse_entered():
    flag = true

 func _on_area_2d_mouse_exited():
    flag = false
```

Предлагаю вариант с созданием флага ([Если нужно узнать поподробнее про флаги](https://dvmn.org/encyclopedia/python_intermediate/flag-variables/)), при включении которого, Ваш код будет описываться в функции _process(), который обновляется каждый фрейм.
Если Ваша проблема является не в этом, то напишите, пожалуйста, предоставьте Ваш код.